# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.zkoss.less.ZKLessServlet.initLessResource when calling ServletContext#getResourcePaths()

Tags: servlets, zk

I am using ZK7, ZKLess.Following is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebAppId" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
      <display-name>SAMPLE</display-name>       
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>zkLess</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.zkoss.less.ZKLessServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>org.zkoss.less.LessResource</param-name>
                <param-value>/css/less/*</param-value><!-- specify to the folder that contains *.less -->
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>org.zkoss.less.OutputFormat</param-name>
                <param-value>.css.dsp</param-value><!-- specify output file suffix, default .css.dsp -->
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>org.zkoss.less.CompressOutput</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value><!-- compress output, default true -->
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>zkLess</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.less</url-pattern><!-- specify to folder that contains *.less -->
        </servlet-mapping>
       <distributable/>
     </web-app>
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` at `org.zkoss.less.ZKLessServlet.initLessResource` when calling `ServletContext.getResourcePaths(LessResourcePath)` while starting the application where `LessResourcePath` is the path containing less files.
How to rectify this issue?

Full Stack Trace for the error is :

```
SEVERE: Servlet /IPSMWeb threw load() exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.zkoss.less.ZKLessServlet.initLessResource(ZKLessServlet.java:121)
    at org.zkoss.less.ZKLessServlet.init(ZKLessServlet.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: maybe show the code as well.

Comment: I am trying to compile the less file(sample.less) to sample.css.dsp for which I have added the following code in web.xml.I am getting that error on application startup.

Comment: Can you attach the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Kenju: can you please stop robo-editing? Several posts you edited have more issues than only the "null pointer exception" part. This looks way too much like reputation harvesting. If there are any robo-approvers out here who actually read this comment somehow, please stop abusing the review system only because you *can* review due to the severely broken access requirements. This is just insane.